# Restoring Individual MyISAM Tables

Tags: mysql, myisam, backup, xtrabackup

I'm using Xtrabackup to perform a MySQL DB restore.

I found some problems when I'm trying to restore individual tables: tables with InnoDB engine can be restored without any problem but I can't find a way to backup and restore MyISAM tables.
Is there a way to restore MyISAM individual tables with Xtrabackup or similar products?

Comment: xtrabackup copies MyISAM tables as well. How do you run xtrabackup?

Comment: with this command: innobackupex --apply-log --export /path/to/backup

Comment: I meant how do you take backups. Anyways, are there *.MYD, *MYI files in the backup?

Comment: Yes, both *.MYD and *.MYI file are present in the backup directory.

Comment: To restore individual MyISAM tables you can copy table.{frm,MYD,MYI} files , execute `FLUSH TABLES` (yes, mysqld may be running) and the restored version will be available on MySQL instance.

Comment: @akuzminsky Please consider changing your comment into an answer, so that it can be accepted by OP.

Answer (score 1):

To restore individual MyISAM tables from XtraBackup:

- Copy `table.{frm,MYD,MYI}` files to MySQL database directory e.g `/var/lib/mysql/sakila`
- Execute `FLUSH TABLES` (yes, mysqld may be running)
- Check the restored version is available on MySQL instance with `SHOW TABLES` and selecting rows from them.